# Ruby Datamapper: retrieving record using param in url path returns null - sometimes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I'm creating a Sinatra App using Datamapper.

With the following route, I'm attempting to print the record for an id. So `localhost:9292/api/1` should return results for `id=1`

inside

```
get '/api/:id' do
```

I tried a couple things with varied results:

```
    thing = Thing.get(params[:id])
    thing.to_json
end
```

outputs 'null', but:

```
    id_param = params[:id]
    id_param
end
```

prints `1` as expected, and:

```
    hardcoded_thing = Thing.get(1)
    hardcoded_thing.to_json
end
```

correctly prints the hardcoded db record with id=1. So I must be losing it..

Any ideas?
Thanks!

---

For reference, here's my model:

```
class Thing
    include DataMapper::Resource
    include BCrypt

    property :id, Serial, :key => true
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime
    property :name, String, :length => 50
    property :cafe_topic, Text
 end
```

Comment: try `params[:id].to_i`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304097/sinatra-matches-paramsid-as-string-type-additional-conversion-needed-to-matc

Comment: @ymonad that did it! If you leave an answer below I'd love to give you the checkmark

Comment: Also, I'm new to Ruby/datamapper - when dealing with errors caused by type mismatches, are null results usually what to expect?

Comment: @Pirijan, this is not an answer to your question, but rather ORM advice. Do not use DataMapper as it is no longer supported.  The last official release was in 2011.  The authors have since replaced it with ROM (Ruby Object Mapper) https://github.com/rom-rb/rom.  Another good option is Sequel https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel.  Both ROM and Sequel are actively maintained alternatives to ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks @bigtunacan, they both look like good alternatives and it looks like I should migrate asap

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get '/api/:id' do |id|
  thing = Thing.get(id)
  thing.to_json
end
```